# update value with innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created counter app which is  two buttons to increment and decrement number and field to display  number , i created with two ways first with  html and js and add event listener to update value with innerHtml , second one with react. vanilla javascritp code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Counter App</h1>
      <h6>Result</h6>
      <div class="result" id="number">0</div>
      <button class="btn" id="incr">+</button>
      <button class="btn" id="decr">-</button>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const incr = document.querySelector('#incr');
    const decr = document.querySelector('#decr');
    const result = document.querySelector('#number');
    let number = 0;
    incr.addEventListener('click', () => {
      number = number + 1;
      result.innerHTML = number;
    });
    decr.addEventListener('click', () => {
      number = number - 1;
      result.innerHTML = number;
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

And here the same code with React  :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Result from './components/Result';

function Button({ number, increment }) {
  return (
    <button className='btn' onClick={() => increment(number)}>
      +
    </button>
  );
}


function BtnContainer({ increment, decrement, number, restHandler }) {
  return (
    <div className='btn-container'>
      <Button number={number} increment={increment} />
      <button className='btn' onClick={() => decrement(number)}>
        -
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => restHandler(number)}>Rest</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);

  function increment(n) {
    setNumber(n + 1);
  }

  function decrement(n) {
    if (n <= 0) return;
    setNumber(n - 1);
  }

  function restHandler(n) {
    setNumber(0);
  }
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <h1>Counter App</h1>
      <h6>Result</h6>
      {/* Props */}
      <Result result={number} />
      <BtnContainer
        increment={increment}
        decrement={decrement}
        number={number}
        restHandler={restHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

So i'm wondering what is the difference ? and what's wrong when update value with innerHtml ?
thanks in  advance .

Comment: Both codes are working fine. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: there is no issue i'm just asking what is the benefit of one way data flow in react ?

Comment: Tool should be adequate to the task. The fact that you don't need machine learning software to sum up 2 and 2, doesn't necessarily mean the one is useless. If you would have a lot of elements like the one you implemented above on different pages across your app wouldn't you like to have that as a reusable component and try to benefit from virtual DOM or would you prefer to copy-paste that manually all over the place?

Comment: @abdulrahmanAbdullah The essence is to have a single source of truth for your states without unnecessary mutations.